# GetMonitorInfo returns wrong window size for secondary display when main display is scaled > 100%

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I have two monitors, my main (laptop) monitor with resolution set to 3840x2160 with 250% scaling and an external monitor at 2560x1440 with 100% scaling. When I maximize my border-less (WindowStyle="None") WPF window on my external monitor the window becomes larger than the display.

[image]

If I set the scaling on my main monitor (the laptop monitor) to 100% the window on the secondary monitor will be maximized correctly.

Why doesn't GetMonitorInfo return the correct size of the secondary display when the main display is scaled?

Thanks!

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfMaximize.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStyle="None">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="60" ResizeBorderThickness="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness}" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="Maximize window" Click="MaximizeWindow" />
        <Button Content="Restore window" Click="RestoreWindow" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SourceInitialized += new EventHandler(FormSourceInitialized);
    }

    private void FormSourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle).AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(FormMaximize.WindowProc));
    }

    private void RestoreWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }
    private void MaximizeWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
```

FormMaximize logic ([from here](https://github.com/multippt/cs2103aug12-w10-4s/blob/f56927a6e9fe751575a06aa9e395a4c525e2503f/Calendo/FormMaximize.cs))

```
public class FormMaximize
{
    private const int WM_GETMINMAXINFO = 0x0024;

    public static IntPtr WindowProc(IntPtr handle, int message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
            case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
                WmGetMinMaxInfo(handle, lParam);
                handled = true;
                break;
        }

        return (IntPtr)0;
    }

    private static void WmGetMinMaxInfo(IntPtr handle, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        MinMaxInfo minmaxInfo = (MinMaxInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MinMaxInfo));

        // Get current monitor information
        int MONITOR_DEFAULT_TO_NEAREST = 0x00000002;
        IntPtr monitor = MonitorFromWindow(handle, MONITOR_DEFAULT_TO_NEAREST);

        if (monitor != IntPtr.Zero) // Not null pointer
        {
            MonitorInfo monitorInfo = new MonitorInfo();
            GetMonitorInfo(monitor, monitorInfo);
            Rectangle workArea = monitorInfo.WorkArea;
            Rectangle monitorArea = monitorInfo.MonitorArea;
            minmaxInfo.MaxPosition.X = Math.Abs(workArea.Left - monitorArea.Left);
            minmaxInfo.MaxPosition.Y = Math.Abs(workArea.Top - monitorArea.Top);
            minmaxInfo.MaxSize.X = Math.Abs(workArea.Right - workArea.Left);
            minmaxInfo.MaxSize.Y = Math.Abs(workArea.Bottom - workArea.Top);
        }

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(minmaxInfo, lParam, true);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Point
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MinMaxInfo
    {
        public Point Reserved;
        public Point MaxSize;
        public Point MaxPosition;
        public Point MinTrackSize;
        public Point MaxTrackSize;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class MonitorInfo
    {
        public int Size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MonitorInfo));
        public Rectangle MonitorArea = new Rectangle();
        public Rectangle WorkArea = new Rectangle();
        public int Flags = 0;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Rectangle
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    // Windows API external reference
    [DllImport("User32")]
    internal static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor, MonitorInfo lpMonitorInfo);
    [DllImport("User32")]
    internal static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr handle, int flags);
}
```

Comment: Is your app [High-DPI aware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows)? If not, then Windows is going to virtualize (ie, lie to you) about the monitor info.

Comment: I have not implemented any High-DPI functionality, and if WPF does not provide this out of the box maybe I should try UWP instead... Although that would be an undertaking so I'd prefer to implement the necessary WPF logic if possible.

Comment: You can easily enable Per-Monitor DPI awareness for WPF by adding application manifest. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process#setting-default-awareness-with-the-application-manifest

Comment: @emoacht Thanks that seems to solve the issue! Add it as an answer to this question if you want and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this as well. What I found was the WmGetMinMaxInfo was getting hit 2x. The first pass the handle was correct so MonitorFromWindow would return the expected info, the second pass it would return the default/primary monitor and cause the behavior you are seeing. As a work around I used MonitorFromPoint from the window's center point which persists when minimized.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SourceInitialized += new EventHandler(FormSourceInitialized);
    }

    private void FormSourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle).AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WindowProc));
    }

    private void RestoreWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }
    private void MaximizeWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }

    private const int WM_GETMINMAXINFO = 0x0024;

    private IntPtr WindowProc(IntPtr handle, int message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
            case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
                var xCenter = (int)(Left + (Width / 2));
                var yCenter = (int)(Top + (Height / 2));
                var windowCenter = new POINT(xCenter, yCenter);
                FormMaximize.WmGetMinMaxInfo(handle, lParam, windowCenter);
                handled = true;
                break;
        }

        return (IntPtr)0;
    }
}
```

```
public class FormMaximize
{

    private static void WmGetMinMaxInfo(IntPtr handle, IntPtr lParam, POINT windowCenter)
    {
        MinMaxInfo minmaxInfo = (MinMaxInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MinMaxInfo));

        // Get current monitor information
        IntPtr monitor = MonitorFromPoint(windowCenter, MONITORINFO.MonitorOptions.MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);

        if (monitor != IntPtr.Zero) // Not null pointer
        {
            MonitorInfo monitorInfo = new MonitorInfo();
            GetMonitorInfo(monitor, monitorInfo);
            Rectangle workArea = monitorInfo.WorkArea;
            Rectangle monitorArea = monitorInfo.MonitorArea;
            minmaxInfo.MaxPosition.X = Math.Abs(workArea.Left - monitorArea.Left);
            minmaxInfo.MaxPosition.Y = Math.Abs(workArea.Top - monitorArea.Top);
            minmaxInfo.MaxSize.X = Math.Abs(workArea.Right - workArea.Left);
            minmaxInfo.MaxSize.Y = Math.Abs(workArea.Bottom - workArea.Top);
        }

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(minmaxInfo, lParam, true);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Point
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MinMaxInfo
    {
        public Point Reserved;
        public Point MaxSize;
        public Point MaxPosition;
        public Point MinTrackSize;
        public Point MaxTrackSize;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class MonitorInfo
    {
        public int Size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MonitorInfo));
        public Rectangle MonitorArea = new Rectangle();
        public Rectangle WorkArea = new Rectangle();
        public int Flags = 0;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Rectangle
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    // Windows API external reference
    [DllImport("User32")]
    internal static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor, MonitorInfo lpMonitorInfo);
    [DllImport("User32")]
    internal static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr handle, int flags);
}
```