# WPF C# get the top left point of the current screen you are on

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to get the topmost and leftmost point of the current screen I am on. Right now, Every time I go to full screen, the app jump to the First monitor.  here is my code:

```
  public void Maximize()
    {
        _oldSize = new Size(_currentWindow.ActualWidth, _currentWindow.ActualHeight);
        _oldLocation = new Point(_currentWindow.Top, _currentWindow.Left);

        double x = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
        double y = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
        _currentWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        _currentWindow.Top = 0;
        _currentWindow.Left = 0;
        _currentWindow.Width = x;
        _currentWindow.Height = y;
        WindowRestoreTwoBoxVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        WindowRestoreOneBoxVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        MaxSizeFlag = true;
    }
```

Is there like an ActiveArea or something like that? because I did not see one.

**Update It is working now:**

I really do not understand, but somehow this worked:

```
    public void Maximize()
    {
        _oldSize = new Size(_currentWindow.ActualWidth, _currentWindow.ActualHeight);
        _oldLocation = new Point(_currentWindow.Top, _currentWindow.Left);

        IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(_currentWindow).Handle;
        MinMaxInfo  windowInfo =  WPFWindowSizes.GetMinMaxInfo(handle);

         _currentWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

         _currentWindow.Top = windowInfo.MaxPosition.Y;
          _currentWindow.Left = windowInfo.MaxPosition.X;
         _currentWindow.Width = windowInfo.MaxSize.X;
        _currentWindow.Height = windowInfo.MaxSize.Y;
        WindowRestoreTwoBoxVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        WindowRestoreOneBoxVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        MaxSizeFlag = true;
    }
 


  public static MinMaxInfo GetMinMaxInfo(IntPtr handle)
    {
        MinMaxInfo minmaxInfo = new MinMaxInfo();

        // Get current monitor information
        int MONITOR_DEFAULT_TO_NEAREST = 0x00000002;
        IntPtr monitor = MonitorFromWindow(handle, MONITOR_DEFAULT_TO_NEAREST);

        if (monitor != System.IntPtr.Zero) // Not null pointer
        {
            MonitorInfo monitorInfo = new MonitorInfo();
            GetMonitorInfo(monitor, monitorInfo);
            Rectangle workArea = monitorInfo.WorkArea;
            Rectangle monitorArea = monitorInfo.MonitorArea;
            minmaxInfo.MaxPosition.X =monitorArea.Left;
            minmaxInfo.MaxPosition.Y = monitorArea.Top;
            minmaxInfo.MaxSize.X = Math.Abs(workArea.Right - workArea.Left);
            minmaxInfo.MaxSize.Y = Math.Abs(workArea.Bottom - workArea.Top);
        }
      
        return minmaxInfo;
    }
```

It is actually doing a fullscreen on the correct monitor. I am not sure why is it working. like at all. I was just trying stuff and this Combination work. Does anyone know why this is working? I guess it doesn't really matter but it would be nice to understand what this code is really doing.

Comment: Obviously, your method works only in primary monitor. BTW why don't you simply set `WindowState = WindowState.Maximized`?

Comment: @emoacht Maximize  hides the task bar. I just want fullscreen. How can I get it to work for the other screens ?

Comment: I see. Then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/69948247/3137337

Comment: @ emoacht,  I looked at the post and it does not answer my question. It does not show how he knows  what current monitor he is on.

Comment: That question exactly solves the same issue. There is no method in .NET to get the monitor dimensions other than primary monitor and so the person resorted to Win32 functions. `IntPtr monitor = MonitorFromWindow(handle, MONITOR_DEFAULT_TO_NEAREST);` is the way to get the monitor where a window currently locates.

Comment: That lParam comes with [WM_GETMINMAXINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-getminmaxinfo) message. Anyway, if you want to keep your original approach, you won't need to handle it. The information you need is `monitorInfo.WorkArea` which represents the dimension of working area of the monitor where the window currently locates.